# Help on interpreting this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> These same perspectives may contribute to a 'glass ceiling' prohibiting relationship-oriented (i.e. feminine) leadership behaviors from being integrated into organization management structures.

I copied this sentence directly from my textbook, and I wanna ask if this sentence is grammatically wrong? Shouldn't 'prohibiting' be 'that prohibits' or shouldn't there be a comma between 'glass ceiling' and 'prohibiting' ?
Btw I'm a Korean high school student

Comment: Not a great sentence. I don't like the scare quotes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scare_quotes in what is purporting to be a scholarly framework. Take a note that the author is a bit pretentious/arrogant and move on.

Comment: The 'glass ceiling' prohibits [certain] behaviors from being integrated into [certain] structures. [Certain] perspectives may contribute to this. The perspectives are the same ones author was just talking about. The structures are organization management structures. The behaviors are relationship-oriented leadership behaviors. The sentence is grammatical but laden with bulky phrases.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct.  "[P]rohibiting..." is a clause modifying "glass ceiling."  Other examples of this sort of thing:

> a talking doll
>
> flowers growing in the garden

Whether you use a comma or not depends on whether "prohibiting..." is an identifying clause or not.  An identifying clause tells you which something you have; it does not get offset with a comma:

> The doctor running late [There's more than one doctor; I mean the one who's running late]
>
> The road leading south [Which road?  The one leading south]

A non-identifying clause does get offset with commas; it describes the noun but doesn't identify it:

> The doctor, running late again,  [We already know which doctor, and we're just finding out that he's running late]
>
> The road, leading south before turning back north again [We already know the road; we're just finding out what path it's taking here]

Identifying clauses are also called "restrictive clauses."

So do we need a comma here?  Depends on whether we're distinguishing between glass ceilings (we're talking about the one that prohibits these behaviors, not the ones that don't) or adding information about the glass ceiling we're talking about.  Since it's not "*the* glass ceiling" but "*a* glass ceiling," and had not mentioned it previously, I'd say we're identifying the glass ceiling, and should leave out the comma.

Here's [more](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clauses-5.html#punctuation).  You can also search for "identifying clause" or "restrictive clause" for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would be clearer with a comma, or with "that prohibits" (or "**, which**"). No it isn't wrong as-is. It is less than clear, but not grammatically incorrect.

Placing commas is not always an exact science. There are certain rules. However many native speakers in their writing will not always put commas in all the "right places". Most native speakers, learn eventually to, not put them in, the wrong places however.

(Above punctuation is meant to be illustrative, not "correct".)

You are learning well; you are developing an "ear" for comma placement.